# マナーモードでも音を鳴らすコードをSwiftで実装したい

Tags: ios, swift

現在、iOSのアプリを作成していますが、マナーモードでも、音を鳴らす処理で悩んでいます。

Objective-Cだと以下のコードになるかと思いますが

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                        sizeof(UInt32),
                        &category);
AudioSessionSetActive = true
```

上記コードを、Swiftに変換する方法がわかりません。
一応、以下のイメージかと考えておりますが、`setProperty`のメソッドが存在しないように思われます。

```
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setProperty(・・・・
audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)
```

どなたか、アドバイスをお願いできないでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

playgroundでエラーがでないところまでしか確認していませんが

```
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
audioSession.setActive(true, error:nil)
```

とすれば同じ内容になると思います。

[AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback と kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback は同じとみて良さそうですが](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8700240/2513010)、必要に応じて setCategoryWithOptionsで、ミキシングを可能にする `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`も指定した方が良いのかもしれません。

Comment: 早速のアドバイスありがとうございます。
今、わかったのですが、動画の撮影音を、以下のコードで鳴らすようにしていますが、この方法だと、上記設定を施しても、音が鳴らないんですね。。。
-------
self.soundIdRing = 1113


AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.soundIdRing)