# ボリューム設定が０（ミュート）であっても音を鳴らす方法

Tags: ios, swift

[マナーモードでも音を鳴らすコード（Swift）について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6045/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%92%E9%B3%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89-swift-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
と似ている質問ですが、これはユーザーがマナーモードにした場合の質問です。
もうひとつ音を出さないようにする方法があり、ボリューム設定を０（ミュート）にした場合の質問です。

現在、動画保存アプリを作成していますが、撮影ボタンをタップされたときに、
音（標準のカメラの音が望ましい）を出すようにしたいと思ってます。

マナーモードでは音を鳴らすことはできましたが、音量を小さく（０にする）するとやはり音が出なくなります。

撮影ボタンが押されたときには、ボリューム設定が０であっても確実に音を出したいと思ってますが、どのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？
どなたか、アドバイスをお願いいたします。

```
var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
audioSession.setActive(true, error:nil)

//再生する音源のURLを生成.
let soundFilePath : NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("aaa", ofType: "mp3")!
let fileURL : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)!

//AVAudioPlayerのインスタンス化.
myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
//AVAudioPlayerのデリゲートをセット.
myAudioPlayer.delegate = self
```

撮影ボタン押下時

```
myAudioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: 質問が重複していますので、以前の質問を更新する形でお願いします。また、別の質問という場合にはタイトルを変えるなどの工夫をお願いします。

Comment: 私はこの質問は重複していないと思いました。　http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1663/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AF%E7%B4%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F%E7%B4%B0%E5%88%86%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D-%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82-%E5%BE%97%E3%81%9F%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E8%A9%B1%E3%82%92%E9%A3%9B%E8%BA%8D%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84

Comment: @natsukitinyak 再オープンしました。

Comment: マナーモードの方の質問が自己解決されているのであれば、対処方法を自己回答して解決済みにされた方がいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちらの質問は、まだ解決していませんので、このまま、アドバイスを待ってみます。
前回の質問は解決済みにします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)
```

これでシステムのシャッター音を鳴らすことができます。
試したらサイレントモードだろうがボリューム0だろうが鳴りました。
特別扱いのサウンドなのかもしれません。

サイレントモードでもシャッター音が鳴るのは日本のiOSの独自仕様のようで、もしかすると他の国のiPhoneだとサイレントモードの時に鳴らないかもしれません。

次の方法で無理やり端末のボリュームを最大にすることもできます。

```
    // import MediaPlayer が必要
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    for view in volumeView.subviews {
        if view is UISlider {
            (view as UISlider).value = 1.0
            break;
        }
    }
```

ただし、いい方法ではないですね。

フレームワークに用意されたクラスの中身を闇雲に操作してるので、とりあえずiOS8では動きましたが、他のOSバージョンでどうなるか分かりません。
よっぽどの事情がなければ使わない方がいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
たしかめてみたところ、確かに、サイレントモードであっても、ボリューム０であっても、鳴りました。
ただ、やはり、AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1113)のメソッドは使えないものですね。
というわけで、動画保存用のシステム音を自前で用意し、上記コードのように、myAudioPlayer.play()での再生を行う方向でいきたいと思います。

※よい方法ではないということですが、こういったアプリを作成する場合、一般的にはどのように実装しているものなのでしょうかね。。

本当にありがとうございました。非常に助かりました。

Comment: yamamoto様のおかげで、無事解決しました。
ありがとうございます。